# Type 'Auth' has no member 'auth' - Google Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I get this error when trying to initialize Google Firebase Auth into my iOS app. I have installed Firebase/Auth using Cocoapods. Error: Type 'Auth' has no member 'auth'. Why does this happen?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class LogIn: UIViewController {


@IBAction func loginClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if !(emailTF.text?.isEmpty)! && !(passwordTF.text?.isEmpty)! {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTF.text, password: passwordTF.text) { (user, error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE: Fixed it. I needed to add Firebase to beginning of the command. Firebase.Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTF.text, password: passwordTF.text)

Comment: No need to import FirebaseAuth. Try to clean (shift + command + k) and re build (command + b) the project

Comment: Which Firebase version have you installed?

Comment: I am running 4.4.0